# How to pull all my tags using the git subtree from another repository?

Tags: git, github, git-subtree, git-tag

#### How to pull all my tags using the git subtree from another repository?

I just created a new repository and added another with git subtree using this command:

```
git subtree add --prefix=Galileo https://github.com/username/Galileo master
```

But it comes without any of the tags on the repository `username/Galileo`. You may see it on https://github.com/username/AlliedModdersFiles. How to get them?

There is this other answer [checkout a specific tag with git subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411468/checkout-a-specific-tag-with-git-subtree), and I got this error:

```
git subtree pull --prefix=Galileo https://github.com/username/Galileo tags/3.2.3
Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.
```

My working tree is clean/there is modifications. Also, I need to handle the tag name conflicting as several subtrees will get tags with the same name as 1.0.0, 1.0.1, from the repository main_repo/SubtreeA, main_repo/SubtreeB, main_repo/SubtreeC, etc.

There is other question [Git subtree tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124044/git-subtree-tags), but I do not get what does mean:

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit v0.1.2 # instead of: Bproject/master (2)
git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u v0.1.2 # instead of: Bproject/master (3)
```

And how could I use it to fetch my tags. Somehow this is related to:

1. [git subtree fetch - unwanted remote tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994409/git-subtree-fetch-unwanted-remote-tags)
2. [How to push tags with git subtree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911466/how-to-push-tags-with-git-subtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the tags just do:

```
git remote add galileo_remote https://github.com/username/Galileo
git fetch --tags
```

But it will get a mess as all tags from all subtrees will conflict with each other. One solution to this is to prefix them all, but it is cumbersome to do so. Then the best approach is to not handle subtrees tags on the main repository, but on the dedicated subtrees repositories.

Now everybody may have awesome tags as `1.0.0` without the need to conflict within each other. This is a better approach also because it will keep the main repository tags clean without the all tags mess from several prefixed subtrees repositories.